# java timer object use the external user timer data

Tags: java, timer

I need to have simple timer in java , where I need to  start timer with my own user time .
actually I get time from external server and my application has to sync with that timer .

Here my Timer object has to start with time which is given my application instead of system time . I tried to use the Timer()  object provided by java.util . but this always takes the system time .

I don't want to modify the system time , I just want my application use the sync time and provide all timer related action from this time .

How to start the timer object with configurable time ..? or is there any approach for this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need that timer to measure durations, have you considered using  System.nanoTime()?